# Pasting elements into layer with Value Relation widget

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a layer, which contains data. Elements from this layer should be pasted into another one, which has value relation widget applyed to its columns. I'm missing values from the first (source) layer while trying to paste them into the second,even if quantity of columns and titles are similar in the first and second. The problem, I suppose, with data types. Can't find manuals or advices for such situation... Need links to read about it...